# Is it advisable to use async/await for a long running operation?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

My application will have to wait a sequence of events from a external system that can take up to 5 minutes to arrive. Is it advisable to use async/await? If it's not, what should you use?

Comment: what "can take up to 5 minutes to arrive"?

Comment: Well.. it depends.... what else is there to do for this application? What machine is it running on? Is this only one task that will have to wait for 5 minutes or more than 10? With the information you provided, I'd say it's ok to use `async/await`, but if you want to do a lot of work in other tasks, maybe not....this question seems either too broad or too opinion based.

Comment: And the question maybe not wether to use `async/await` or not, but how to start your Task. See [Task.Factory.StartNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321263.aspx) and the [TaskCreationOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx)

Comment: `async`/`await` may not be the only good option in such a case, but it is *a* good option

Comment: For long running tasks don't use async-await, the number of available threads in the thread pool is limited. The extra time needed to start a new thread is small in comparison to the long running task. Consider using System.ComponentModel.BackGroundWorker: Easy to start with parameters, easy to report progress, easy to report the result and easy to cancel. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your Task as this, it *may be* ok. This starts the task as *"long running"* and the TPL will probably schedule it on a different CPU and will not use a ThreadPool thread:

```
void RunLongTask()
{
     // long work to do

     // in case of wpf you can report progress to ui
     Dispatcher.Invoke(ProgressDelegate, 0);

     // more work

     Dispatcher.Invoke(ProgressDelegate, 1);

     // etc...
}
async Task RunLongTaskAsync()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(RunLongTask, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

But those questions always depend on the overall work load for your application and the machine it is running on. If you have enough resources, who cares about one long running task. But if your machine is small and you want to do a lot of other stuff... take care.

Comment: I get it, René, but within that code, how do I "notify" the UI when some event occurs in the worker thread? Using SyncronizationContext.Current or a Dispatcher.Invoke?

Comment: You did not specify any UI framework (eg. Windows.Forms, WPF) in your question. Neither did you ask for notifications. Anyway, since you suggest `Dispatcher.Invoke` I guess your talking about WPF, so yes, to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` seems appropriate.

Comment: Updated my answer and added some progress reporting calls.